# Illustrator - Text to SVG paths without fill

Tags: adobe-illustrator, svg

When I create text in illustrator and export it to SVG with the option `Convert to Outlines`, I get the following:

[image]

This is fine, except in the generated `svg` file there is inline CSS with the following:

`<style>.cls-1{fill:#231f20;}</style>`

If I change that to `.cls-1{fill: none; stroke: #231f20;}`, I then get the following:

[image]

This proves that the generated SVG is actually an *outline* around the letters, instead of the path *through* the letters. How can I get illustrator to generate the latter option?

Edit: Since no answers so far, here's more detail on what I'm trying to do. If I convert text to outlines, I get the following:

[image]

What I'm not clear is on the next step. Suppose I want to create "inner" paths that are lines and curves halfway between the inner and outer lines. Here's an example for the letter A:

[image]

In this case, 3 line paths are needed for the letter A.

Is there a way to generate these inner paths using a command or set of commands in illustrator?

Comment: Hello Eric and welcome to GraphicDesign! Let us know if you have any questions about how the site works

Comment: [This answer](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/a/69181/52050) should help.

Comment: There is no automatic way to get the skeleton of a font.