# Circular blend Illustrator

Tags: adobe-illustrator, blending-objects

Using Illustrator, I am trying to blend objects in a circular fashion but can't seem to find a satisfying solution. I have considered using the rotate tool, copying the rotated object around a central axis and then holding down command-d to complete the "blend" but find this method inefficient. I have also considered replacing the spline of a blend with a circle, but it seems that no matter what, the blend can never go past 3/4 of a circle (see GIF below). Am I missing something?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This happens when you replace the spine of a blend with a closed path. The blend can't use the same point as a beginning and end point so you get a section of your path not being used.

To fix the issue just use the Scissors Tool (<kbd>C</kbd>) on the path to create an open path.

Comment: Works partially because I lose the alignment to path

Comment: That is a separate issue. Blend doesn't always work well with complex curves. You can break your blend in to smaller sections if you need to.

Comment: Not exactly the same situation but you can see what I mean by breaking the blend in to smaller section [in this answer](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/a/69181/52050).

Comment: @luimeme I just recreated the same blend as your example and cut the path as in my answer and there were no issues with alignment?

Comment: I was cutting the path BEFORE blending. Thank you very much this was a major annoyance.

Answer (score 0):

<kbd>Object</kbd>><kbd>Path</kbd>><kbd>Add Anchor Points</kbd> will add more points around the circle.

Blends seem to behave a little more as expected if you add some anchor points to the circle before setting it as the new spine.

Comment: Works partially because I lose the alignment to path

Comment: Adding anchor points will help but it's better to add the points yourself or use an open path by cutting the path yourself. Using *Add Anchor Points* will only half the section of the path that isn't being used.