# Brush outline and fill

Tags: adobe-illustrator, stroke, brush

I have made a pattern brush to apply for a hand drawn brush. It usually works nicely, but yesterday it went started acting up.

When I draw, I have a solid outline and invisible fill (which looks like a solid line and has only one stroke when I select it) and then apply the custom pattern brush. This one particular brush stroke (rather complex that I created all my artwork around) is two outline strokes and not a solid line. How do I manage to make it a solid line that I can apply my pattern brush to?

[image]

Comment: You may need to upload some screenshots as I'm having trouble picturing what you have and what you're trying to do

Comment: Ok so you have an outlined stroke that gives you a double stroke when you reapply a stroke. You want a single path to apply a brush stroke to, correct?

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your situation correctly, you could use the method I described here:

- [Technique for finding the centerline of a curved object](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/a/69181/52050).

Essentially you use the blend tool with 1 step.

You may need to split your stroke in to more manageable sections before you begin for the blend to work correctly. You can find a more in depth explanation in the linked answer.

---

1. Use the Scissors tool (<kbd>C</kbd>) to cut each end of you outlined stroke so that you have 2 distinct paths.

[image]

2. Open the blend options (**Object → Blend → Blend Options...**) and set spacing to "Specified Steps" with a value of 1.

[image]

3. Select both paths and create your blend (**Object → Blend → Make**).

[image]

4. Expand the blend (**Object → Blend → Expand**) and delete the original paths.

[image]

5. Apply your brush stroke.

[image]